# From classified image to topology in ArcInfo

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, topology, classification

I have some coastal 4 band imagery that I have classified to designate land, water, and undetermined. I want to convert this to polygons with topology, and significantly simplify the polygons.

If I convert the raster to vector, then try to apply a topology, then simplify the polygons, Arc Crashes.

(Raster to Polygon>Select By Attribute x3>Export to FeatureDataset as 3 separate classes>Create Topology in ArcCatalog. Started with only Can't-overlap-self rules, but have also tried Can't overlap each other rules, as well as trying one rule at a time. I have tried validating in Arc catalog, with a validation failed error followed by an ArcCatalog Crash. I have tried not validating until in an edit session in ArcMap, which results in a freeze then a crash. I deleted the topology after each error and started a new one.)

If I try to split these polygons, I get the empty output bug in ArcInfo.

(Raster to Polygon>Select By Attribute x3>Export to FeatureDataset as 3 separate classes> Extract/Split tool using a fishnet as the split features> Processes Polygons, completes without error, copies everything from dataset of input feature to Target Workspace, doesn't split polygons. Have seen threads from older versions having this bug.)

If I convert raster to vector, then simplify, I end up with tons of gaps and overlaps left to fix. (Which defeats the purpose of going to a topology first.)

I've got to think this is a fairly common conversion. Is there a specific trick or workflow that I am missing here to accomplish this? Or am I at the mercy of ESRI bugs?

ArcMap / ArcInfo with spatial analysis version 10.0 SP5.

EDIT:Added specific workflows above. Although I've tried a few other variations using mostly the same tools. The usual save and close between steps. Export as a whole before exporting by attribute.

Comment: Would you be able to provide more specific details like which tools (by name) you have used and what exact error messages you are seeing?  If so, just edit them into your original question.

Comment: Have you tried to split your dataset into smaller pieces (by grid) and then try the raster to vector, apply topology, and simplify polygons?

Comment: Re: Smaller pieces by grid: I have. Made a fishnet. A few actually of different sizes. I can't get the split tool to work. I thought about doing a bunch of clips from a larger blocked fishnet, but haven't tried it yet. Will try that now.